# Android vibrate() function

Tags: android, vibration, android-vibration

I am developing an Android app, and I require to use the vibrating function of the phone.

```
vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

if(vibrator != null){
    Toast.makeText(Game.this, "it`s not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    // the result is not null
}

vibrator.vibrate(100);
```

This code works perfectly on S3, S4, a Sony Ericson model, yet it doesn`t seem to do anything on my Huawei Ascend P6.

My Huawei supports vibrations, since many other apps have it. Any help is appreciated.

The permission is added in the manifest, the code was triple-checked in order to ensure there are no NullPointerExceptions or any other kind.

Comment: Why do you have vibrator.vibrate(100); outside the null check? That's going to throw a null reference.

Comment: I put the null check there simply to verify if the vibrator is not null. However, I never had a NullPointerException with this instance of Vibrator.